# How to parse PNaCl as human readable LLVM IR?

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir, google-nativeclient

I have a `.pexe` and want to get the LLVM IR code. How can this be done? This is the file I want to convert to LLVM IR: [NaClAMBullet.pexe](https://storage.googleapis.com/gonacl/demos/publish/236779/bullet/NaClAMBullet.pexe)

I don't understand why it is not already readable LLVM IR code:

> A PNaCl portable executable (pexe in short) is a single LLVM IR module.

Source: [Google Native Client Reference](https://developer.chrome.com/native-client/reference/pnacl-bitcode-abi)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [PNaCl toolchain](https://developer.chrome.com/native-client/devguide/devcycle/building#the-pnacl-toolchain) contains many tools to manipulate PNaCl and LLVM files, including `pnacl-dis` and `pnacl-bcdis`. A `.pexe` is indeed create from a single LLVM IR module, but it ins't the same as an LLVM IR module: the PNaCl bitcode is stable and different from LLVM IR.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I didn't know Google provided such easy to use tools for this. I have tried multiple LLVM tools, but it seems Google has changed quite a few things in several of the components of the toolchain. It might be obvious to other people, but I am very new to compiled languages and have only used `clang` and self written makefiles...

Comment: The output is on half a million lines. Do you know how to remove all code generated by `Pepper.js`/`NaCl SDK` to be left with just the part that was written in the original `C`/`C++`-file?

Comment: Your best bet for that is to use the object file generated from just that C file rather than the final linked executable. The object files are "regular" LLVM bitcode and can be used with any PNaCl or LLVM tool.

Comment: @Derek Thank you :) I wanted to look at some `.pexe`-files that are already compiled. But if it is much hassle without the object files, I guess I'll figure out something else to spend my time on.